# init method in jersey jax-rs web service

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, init

I'm new with jax-rs and have build a web service with jersey and glassfish.

What I need is a method, which is called once the service is started. In this method I want to load a custom config file, set some properties, write a log, and so on ...

I tried to use the constructor of the servlet but the constructor is called every time a GET or POST method is called.

what options I have to realize that?

Please tell, if some dependencies are needed, give me an idea how to add it to the pom.xml (or else)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve it, depending on what you have available in your application:

### Using [`ServletContextListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) from the Servlet API

Once JAX-RS is built on the top of the Servlet API, the following piece of code will do the trick:

```java
@WebListener
public class StartupListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Perform action during application's startup
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Perform action during application's shutdown
    }
}
```

### Using [`@ApplicationScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/ApplicationScoped.html) and [`@Observes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/event/Observes.html) from CDI

When using JAX-RS with CDI, you can have the following:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class StartupListener {

    public void init(@Observes 
                     @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) ServletContext context) {
        // Perform action during application's startup
    }

    public void destroy(@Observes 
                        @Destroyed(ApplicationScoped.class) ServletContext context) {
        // Perform action during application's shutdown
    }
}
```

In this approach, you must use [`@ApplicationScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/ApplicationScoped.html) from the `javax.enterprise.context` package and **not** [`@ApplicationScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/bean/ApplicationScoped.html) from the `javax.faces.bean` package.

### Using [`@Startup`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/Startup.html) and [`@Singleton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/Singleton.html) from EJB

When using JAX-RS with EJB, you can try:

```java
@Startup
@Singleton
public class StartupListener {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // Perform action during application's startup
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        // Perform action during application's shutdown
    }
}
```

---

If you are interested in reading a properties file, check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/883858/1426227). If you are using CDI and you are open to add [Apache DeltaSpike](https://deltaspike.apache.org) dependencies to your project, considering having a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31361654/1426227).

Comment: okay, I tried to use EJB 3.1 in my project for the last method, add Startup and Singleton but when I start the service the init() method isn't called. What did I missed?

Comment: @Surras Try the first approach, using `ServletContextListener` from the Servlet API.

Comment: I've tried the first one but I got an exception. I thougth it occours because I already use the jersey-servlet-container in my pom.xml and I can't load both, am I wrong?

Comment: okay, now the first one worked (I've used the wrong dependency in pom.xml). But how can I declare variables which are accessable in my GET and POST methods (and which are singleton)?

Comment: @Surras *how can I declare variables which are accessable in my GET and POST methods* Is really unclear to me.

Comment: Okay sorry. What I mean is: at init I put an image path in a string variable for example and have a counter as integer, init with 0. When a POST method is called, I need to read the image path variable and increase the counter by 1. How can I declare and access these variables in my whole application?

Comment: @Surras Use a singleton to hold this values. Or, depending on your requirements, use a database. However, I think it's a different question, outside of the scope of the original one.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will ask a new question and leave the link as a comment here.

Comment: I ask a new question for singleton variables. You can find the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39835248/3603602 thanks for help!