# Singleton variables in Jersey web service

Tags: rest, jersey, singleton, jax-rs

I have a RESTful web service based on **JAX-RS** and **Jersey**. I have a bunch of GET and POST Methods and inside of it i need "global" variables.

I have an initialization method with **ServletContextListener** and it's contextInitialized-Method for write some log files and do other stuff. In this method I want to declare variables wich I can access from anywhere in my application.

here are my code:

```
    @WebListener
    public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
//these are the variables I need in my other methods
        public String imagePath;
        public int entryCount;
        public int registeredUsers;
        public Connection connection;

        @Override
        public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
            System.out.println("initialization of service stared");
            System.out.println("reading config...");

            Configuration config = ConfigManager.readConfig("../service_config.xml");
            this.imagePath = config.getImagePath();

            System.out.println("try to get databse connection");
            connection = ConnectionHelper.getConnection(config.getDbName(),
                                                        config.getDbPassword(),
                                                        config.getDbUser());

            System.out.println("database connection successful established");
            // here are some db actions...
        }

        @Override
        public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
            System.out.println("shutdown service");
        }
    }
```

For example:
At init, I read an config file, count some stats from database and read an image path-string for a directory out of my config file.

When a GET method is called, I want to read the String variable of the image path and increase a counter by 1.

```
@Path("/entries")
public class EntryService {
@GET
    @Path("/images/{imageId}")
    @Produces({"image/png"})
    public Response getEntryImage(@PathParam("imageId") long imageId) {
        String filePath = <* HERE I NEED THE IMAGE PATH FROM INIT *>;
        File file = new File(filePath + imageId + ".png");

        if (file.exists()) {
            Response.ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
            response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=image_from_server.png");

            return response.build();
        } else {
            Response.ResponseBuilder response = Response.status(204);
            return response.build();
        }
    }
}
```

How do I realize that? (I read something about EJB and Singleton-Annotation but didn't get it work).

If a library or component needs some extra dependencies in my pom.xml file, please tell me how to implement it.

Comment: [Could you show a bit of code?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I edit my post with some code snippets

Comment: @Surras you can do that using bindings in jersey. Where do you create your jersey application (for EntryService)? In the same place, you can create a binding to a configuration bean, which you will then be able to inject into all jersey managed services

Comment: @pandaadb excuse me, but I don't know where exactly the create point of the application is. I'm new with web services and create a project with IntelliJ IDEA CE and the IDE create the whole structure of the project. Could you explain me, how I create a binding?

Comment: @Surras Do you have a web.xml? Maybe a resourceConfig class? Application class? Something is creating your jersey runtime and you'll need access to that to add bindings to it (I believe). How does your application start?

Comment: @pandaadb I have a web.xml (a edit my post later with its content). I dont have a resourceConfig nor an Application class. The application is started with a script embedded in the IDE, wich compile, starts a tomcat server and deploy the server to it (I think)